# Windows 8.1; Python 2.7: `import gtk` produces ImportError:DLL load failed?

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

More completely, this is the traceback:

```
A:\hamster-src\hamster\win>python hamster-win.py
Running from source folder, modifying PYTHONPATH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hamster-win.py", line 35, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "A:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 30, in <mod
ule>
    import gobject as _gobject
  File "A:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gobject\__init__.py", line 26, in
<module>
    from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \
  File "A:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\glib\__init__.py", line 22, in <mo
dule>
    from glib._glib import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have installed GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment, as available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtk-win/

I installed PyGTK using the all-in-one installer.

It still seems that the right DLLs cannot be found? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of the GTK+ environment did you install?